# Adding a LookupComboBox to a CXGrid cell

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Apart from getting LookupComboBox on a cell via the below given method is there any other way?

`-Select a column
-From Properties select LookupComboBox
-fill out the required data suchas listsource, listfieldnames etc`

The reason behind for looking an alternative solution is i am getting data in CXGrid by joining multiple tables and thus when i use the above method then i run into errors

i am looking for a example where i am able to LookupComboBox on a cell of CXGrid , Help!!

**`Updated Question`**

With the below suggestions i have tried to re-frame my question i think this should make sense now

I have a table Employee and Department

`Employee
EmpID, EmpName, DepID`

`Department
DepID, DepartmentName`

So in the cxGrid What I want is

`EmpID, EmpName, DepartmentName`

Thus the query which was given to **GridDataset** to fetch the data was

`SELECT EmpID, EmpName, DepartmentName FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Department ON Department.DepID =  Employee.DepID`

Next step is DepartmentName field in CXGrid should be edittable via a lookupcombobox
Thus 
-Select a column(DepartmentName)
-From Properties select LookupComboBox
-fill out the required data suchas listsource, listfieldnames etc
**Here the is ListSource is another dataset which is refering to Department with KeyFieldName as DepID**

With all this setting when i try to view the data in cxgrid by doing GridDataset.open then i get the following error message
**"Could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type (Boolean)"**

Comment: "... and thus ..." I can't immediately see why the fact that you are populating the grid from a multi-table join should result in "errors".  In any case, you don't say what the errors are, so how could readers possibly help with so little to go on.  I think you should add to your q the details of a) the SQL join you are using to populate the grid, b) what the settings are for populating the lookupcombo and c) the **exact** text of the error message(s).

Comment: @MartynA 
This is one of the error
 "'Could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type (Boolean)'"

By the way if you could share any alternative method then it would be great . 
some what similar manner : [link](http://www.nsonic.de/blog/2007/05/adding-a-combobox-to-a-cell/)

Just a note i am not suppose to change the present working i.e referring to join.

Comment: Sorry, you can't expect help if readers have to guess the relevant details which you fail to provide in your q, f.i. the datatype of the db field that the combobox is for.

Comment: @MartynA
datatype of the db field is string

Comment: I appreciate that you are new to SO and have not yet learned hot to do stuff, but please read: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Spend some time to digest it completely. We are eager to help you but we simply can not read your mind, neither your screen. Also, when asked for aditional information, provide it in full, as an **edit** of your question. See the "**edit**" button just under the tags of your question. Do it now and provide the response to @MartynA a), b) and c) in full.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg Thank you i will go through the suggestions.

Comment: @MartynA i have updated the question

Comment: Bravo for your updated q!  I've updated my answer with a sample project that should do what you want, but without the error you've been getting.  The source of that error is still a mystery to me, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with your much-improved q, I have been unable to reproduce the error you report
so that must be caused by something you're doing that is still missing from your q.

However, now that I've a better idea of what you're trying to do, I do have a fully-working test project, and I've included as much as I think
you'll need of it to set up a similar project yourself.

Seems to me that regardless of the error you get with your project, it is doomed to
failure for the following reason:

- Since your GridDataSet SELECT statement doesn't include the DepID value in the Employee
  row, there's no way that this could be updated on the server and retrieved subsequently.

So, my version *does* include the Employee DepID column in the SELECT statement
and I've included a column for it in the cxGrid so that it's easier to see what's going
on - obviously you could hide or omit the DepID column in the cxGrid.

Projects often don't work as expected because of settings buried in the Object Inspector
especially with objects as complicated as the cxGrid.  To avoid that and prove that
my project actually works, I've done almost everything in code, including creating
and populating the Employee and Department tables and setting up the `lookupcombobox`.
The only thing I haven't done in code is to create the cxGrid columns, because that was
too irksome to do - this is what's in the DFM extract I've included instead.

Code extract

```
const
  scCreateData =
  'create table Employee'#13#10
   + '(EmpID int primary key,'#13#10
   + 'EmpName nvarchar(10),'#13#10
   + 'DepID int)'#13#10
   + ''#13#10
   + 'create table Department'#13#10
   + '(DepID int primary key,'#13#10
   + 'DepartmentName nvarchar(10)'#13#10
   + ')'#13#10
   + ''#13#10
   + 'insert Employee(EmpID, EmpName, DepID) values (1, ''Joe Blow'', 1)'#13#10
   + 'insert Employee(EmpID, EmpName, DepID) values (2, ''Jane Doe'', 2)'#13#10
   + ''#13#10
   + 'insert Department(DepID, DepartmentName) values(1, ''HR'')'#13#10
   + 'insert Department(DepID, DepartmentName) values(2, ''Other'')'#13#10
   ;

  scGetGridData =
  'SELECT e.EmpID, e.EmpName, e.DepID, D.DepartmentName FROM Employee e'#13#10
   + 'INNER JOIN Department d ON d.DepID =  E.DepID';

  scGetLookUpData = 'Select * from Department';


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //  Create Grid and Lookup tables and populate them
  GridDataSet.SQL.Text := scCreateData;
  GridDataSet.ExecSQL;

  LookUpDataSet.SQL.Text := scGetLookUpData;
  LookUpDataSet.Open;

  GridDataSet.SQL.Text := scGetGridData;
  GridDataSet.Open;

  //  Set up lookupcombo on DepartmentName column
  cxGrid1DBTableView1DepartmentName.PropertiesClass := TcxLookUpComboBoxProperties;
  TcxLookUpComboBoxProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1DepartmentName.Properties).KeyFieldNames := 'DepartmentName';
  TcxLookUpComboBoxProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1DepartmentName.Properties).ListFieldNames := 'DepID;DepartmentName';
  TcxLookUpComboBoxProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1DepartmentName.Properties).ListFieldIndex := 1;
  TcxLookUpComboBoxProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1DepartmentName.Properties).ListSource := dsLookUpDataSet;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin

  // Tidyup  WARNING - drops tables
  GridDataSet.Close;
  GridDataSet.SQL.Text := 'drop table Employee';
  GridDataSet.ExecSql;

  GridDataSet.SQL.Text := 'drop table Department';
  GridDataSet.ExecSql;

end;
```

DFM extract

```
object cxGrid1DBTableView1: TcxGridDBTableView
  Navigator.Buttons.CustomButtons = <>
  DataController.DataSource = dsGridDataSet
  DataController.Summary.DefaultGroupSummaryItems = <>
  DataController.Summary.FooterSummaryItems = <>
  DataController.Summary.SummaryGroups = <>
  object cxGrid1DBTableView1EmpID: TcxGridDBColumn
    DataBinding.FieldName = 'EmpID'
  end
  object cxGrid1DBTableView1EmpName: TcxGridDBColumn
    DataBinding.FieldName = 'EmpName'
  end
  object cxGrid1DBTableView1DepID: TcxGridDBColumn
    DataBinding.FieldName = 'DepID'
  end
  object cxGrid1DBTableView1DepartmentName: TcxGridDBColumn
    DataBinding.FieldName = 'DepartmentName'
    PropertiesClassName = 'TcxLookupComboBoxProperties'
    Properties.KeyFieldNames = 'DepartmentName'
    Properties.ListColumns = <
      item
        FieldName = 'DepID'
      end
      item
        FieldName = 'DepartmentName'
      end>
    Properties.ListFieldIndex = 1
    Properties.ListSource = dsLookUpDataSet
  end
end
```

So, the literal answer to your q

> Apart from getting LookupComboBox on a cell via the below given method is there any other way?

is that you don't need another way, just make sure that your SELECT statement retrieves all the data you need and then configure the `lookupcombobox` correctly.

**Original answer follows:**  I'll edit it down or out once I know
the new version works for you.

<s>You haven't provided sufficient information in your q to reproduce the
problem you're having, nor clearly indicated where (in your code) the error arises.</s>

So the following is at best a work-around, and is based on the idea that you can
use a ComboBox instead of a LookupComboBox and populate it yourself in code.

Try this:

- Set your cxGrid column's `Properties` to `ComboBox`
- In your FormCreate event, add the following code

Code

```
//  In the following, my column's db fieldname is "Value"
cxGrid1DBTableView1Value.PropertiesClass := TcxComboBoxProperties;
TcxComboBoxProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1Value.Properties).Items.Add('One');
TcxComboBoxProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1Value.Properties).Items.Add('Two');
TcxComboBoxProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1Value.Properties).Items.Add('Three');
```

At runtime, you should see a pull-down list containing the entries "One", "Two", "Three".

Obviously, if you want the combobox to list values that depend on the data values in the
current cxGrid data row, you will need to clear the combobox `Items` list and repopulate
it when your grid's dataset scrolls (using its `AfterScroll` event).  Where you get the values from to add to the `Items` list is entirely up to you.

If you don't want to use a ComboBox instead of a LookUpComboBox, then the best I can
suggest is to trace the code of a working example of the LookUpComboBox type for
the column's properties and see if you can mimic what it does in code of your own.
That, or debug the actual problem you're having, because readers can't do that for you!

**Update**

> i am looking for a example where i am able to LookupComboBox on a cell of CXGrid

The dataset I'm using has a two-character field, 'CountryCode'.  The following additional code in the `FormCreate` will add a LookUpCombo in its column connected to a TClientDataSet `cdsCountry`.

```
  cdsCountry.FieldDefs.Add('CountryCode', ftString, 2);
  cdsCountry.FieldDefs.Add('CountryName', ftString, 80);

  cdsCountry.CreateDataSet;
  cdsCountry.InsertRecord(['', '']);
  cdsCountry.InsertRecord(['GB', 'United Kingdom']);
  cdsCountry.InsertRecord(['FR', 'France']);
  cdsCountry.InsertRecord(['DE', 'Germany']);

  cxGrid1DBTableView1CountryCode.PropertiesClass := TcxLookUpComboBoxProperties;
  TcxLookUpComboBoxProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1CountryCode.Properties).KeyFieldNames := 'CountryCode';
  TcxLookUpComboBoxProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1CountryCode.Properties).ListFieldNames := 'CountryCode;CountryName';
  TcxLookUpComboBoxProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1CountryCode.Properties).ListSource := dsCountry;
```

Comment: I really appreciate you for taking out your precious time.
I tried both of the above given solutions before posting in SO.
I am trying my side.
Thank you.

Comment: It got resolved when i changed the KeyFieldName from DepID to Description.  
Thankyou